# Getting first parent's fields via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to get the fields and values of my object's first parent. My current code is this:

```
Class<? extends Object> cls = obj.getClass();
Field[] fields = cls.getDeclaredFields();
for ( Field field : fields )
{
    String fieldName = field.getName();
    String fieldValue = field.get(obj);
}
```

My class structure is similar to this:

```
class A
{
    int x;
}

class B extends A
{
    int y;
}

class C extends B
{
    int z;
}
```

Now, I pass a C object to the method and I want to get all fields from C and B, but not from A. Is there a way to do this (using reflection, I don't want to implement other methods)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Luchian, use the [getSuperclass()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29) method to obtain a reference to a Class object that represents a superclass type of the object in question. After that it is going to be easy for you to get fields the same way you do in your example.

Answer (score 11):

Create a method

```
public static void printFieldsFor(Class cls, Object obj) {
  Field[] fields = cls.getDeclaredFields();
  for ( Field field : fields ) {
    String fieldName = field.getName();
    String fieldValue = field.get(obj);
  }
}

printFieldsFor(object.getClass(), obj);
printFieldsFor(object.getClass().getSuperclass(), obj);
```

or use a loop

```
for(Class cls = object.getClass(); 
    cls!=null && cls!=A.class; 
    cls = cls.getSuperclass()) {
  for(Field field : cls.getDeclaredFields()) {
     String fieldName = field.getName();
     String fieldValue = field.get(obj);
     // do something with the field.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author pablo.barbosa (2017-08-15)
 */
public class ReflectionUtil {

    /**
     * Hiding constructor. The methods are statics
     */
    private ReflectionUtil() {
        // Hiding constructor
    }

    public static List<Field> getInheritedDeclaredFields(Class<?> fromClass, Class<?> stopWhenClass) {
        if (stopWhenClass == null) {
            stopWhenClass = Object.class;
        }
        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();

        Class<?> cls = fromClass;
        do {
            classes.add(cls);
            cls = cls.getSuperclass();
        } while (cls != null && !cls.equals(stopWhenClass));

        for (int i = classes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(classes.get(i).getDeclaredFields()));
        }

        return fields;
    }

    public static Field getInheritedDeclaredField(Class<?> fromClass, String fieldName, Class<?> stopWhenClass) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        if (stopWhenClass == null) {
            stopWhenClass = Object.class;
        }

        Class<?> cls = fromClass;
        do {
            Field field;
            try {
                field = cls.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                if (field != null) {
                    return field;
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
                // Nothing. We'll try to get field from superclass
            }
            cls = cls.getSuperclass();
        } while (cls != null && !cls.equals(stopWhenClass));

        // If we got here, we'll throw an exception
        throw new NoSuchFieldException(fieldName);
    }

    public static Object getInheritedDeclaredFieldValue(Object obj, String fieldName, Class<?> stopWhenClass) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = getInheritedDeclaredField(obj.getClass(), fieldName, stopWhenClass);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.get(obj);
    }

}
```

Comment: Usually its better to not just post the code with the answer. But also explain why.

Answer (score -4):

you can simply get fields from any class using this code no mater its parent or child class

```
for (Field field : YourClassName.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
  //fields
}
```

Comment: Wrong : from javadoc : Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields, *but excludes inherited fields*