# How to get fields of parent class using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, field

Suppose there is a class :

```
class A {
  int a;
}
```

And then there is a child of class A :

```
class B extends A {
  int b;
}
```

if i call `B.class.getDeclaredFields()` i'll only get 'b' field.

Now how can i get fields of parent class in this case 'a'.

Comment: You can use `getField()` with public fields. Otherwise, you need to loop through parent classes yourself.

Comment: Might helpfull

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966466/getting-first-parents-fields-via-reflection

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should call it with something like this:

```
B.class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields();
```